# How do I write an xpath expression for an element following another with certain text?

Tags: xpath

How do I construct an xpath expression in which I want to get the <p> element following a <p> element with a child <strong> element with the text, "About this event:".

In other words, what path expression will give me the "<p>" element with the "Hello" text following the <P> with the <Strong> text below …

```
<p>
    <strong>About this event:</strong>
    …
</p>
<p>Hello</p>
```

? -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//p[strong[.='About this event:']]/following-sibling::p
```

or

```
//p[strong[.='About this event:']]/following-sibling::p[.='Hello']
```

Comment: you missed `]` in the second selector before `/followin...`

Comment: I Fixed it. Why didn't you fixed it by yourself??

Comment: I think you need a minimum of 2000 rep to edit other users posts (which @alehdouhi doesnt have yet).

Comment: Don't want to consume mods time on approving this edit. Actually don't know how it exactly works

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//p[normalize-space(strong)='About this event:']/following-sibling::p
```

You can also narrow this down to the first `p` by adding `[1]`:

```
//p[normalize-space(strong)='About this event:']/following-sibling::p[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be do-able.  Here's the output from Perl's `xpath` tool:

```
so zacharyyoung$ xpath so.xml '//p[strong = "About this event:"]/following-sibling::p[1]'
Found 1 nodes:
-- NODE --
<p>Hello</p>
```

The XPath is `//p[strong = "About this event:"]/following-sibling::p[1]`